# how to add youtube link in block?

Tags: magento2, home-page, video, youtube

Can I create a block with a youtube video inside on homepage? and youtube link can be modified from admin page?
how can I do it without pagebuilder and magento commerce?

Comment: you try using iframe **`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/
oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen></iframe>`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow these steps to achieve the above scenario

1- Create a custom variable from

> Admin-> System-> Other Settings-> Custom Variable

[image]

Then save the configurations.

2- Create a block and add an iframe embed code. Add a custom variable that you want to link.

[image]

Comment: will try that now. thank you!

Comment: please accept the answer if the above solution works for you.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/euNkcDq.png
It shows homepage instead of youtube link.
https://i.imgur.com/Yl2jUlV.png
https://i.imgur.com/KYFg8g5.png
I wonder why?

Comment: Can you please show how you set up the URL from the custom variable? It works all fine on my end. https://imgur.com/a/vjvjbFw

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Wp8izlE.png
https://i.imgur.com/ZbT73iU.png
https://i.imgur.com/Qgnz4Fy.png

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/V186jhq.png something worked think so. thanks.

Comment: do you have an idea why youtube refused to connect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337086/my-youtube-video-wont-show-in-iframe/36337328 that helped.

Comment: Yes, you need to use embed/ instead of watch.
And then clean the cache.